# LibSVM testin the model: i always get one result for all features

Tags: java, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

Im trying to use LibSVM with java,
When i try to predict the label i always get one result for all the features!

```
            param.svm_type = svm_parameter.NU_SVC;
            param.kernel_type = svm_parameter.RBF;
            param.gamma = 0.5;
            param.nu = 0.4;
            param.cache_size = 20000;
            param.C = 1000;
            param.eps = 0.001;
            param.p = 0.1;
```

size de feature training SVM: 913

optimization finished, #iter = 453

nu = 0.9923329682365827

obj = -906.0, rho = 1.0

nSV = 906, nBSV = 906

Total nSV = 906

reel : 0.0 predict : 1.0

reel : 1.0 predict : 1.0

reel : 0.0 predict : 1.0

reel : 1.0 predict : 1.0

reel : 1.0 predict : 1.0

reel : 0.0 predict : 1.0

reel : 1.0 predict : 1.0

reel : 0.0 predict : 1.0

reel : 1.0 predict : 1.0

this is the prediction fonction!

```
public static void test( svm_model model, HashMap<Integer, Double> labelTest,
        HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Double>> featuresTesting ) {
    int NombreLigne = featuresTesting.size();
    for ( Integer testInstance : featuresTesting.keySet() ) {
        double label = labelTest.get( testInstance );
        HashMap<Integer, Double> tmp = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
        tmp = featuresTesting.get( testInstance );
        int numFeatures = tmp.keySet().size();
        svm_node[] x = new svm_node[numFeatures];
        int featureIndx = 0;
        for ( Integer feature : tmp.keySet() ) {
            x[featureIndx] = new svm_node();
            x[featureIndx].index = feature;
            x[featureIndx].value = tmp.get( feature );
            featureIndx++;

        }

        double d = svm.svm_predict( model, x );

        System.out.println( "real : " + label + " prediction : " + svm.svm_predict( model, x ) );

    }
```

Comment: increase your C value. nBSV equal to nSV suggest that it is too small (this means that all lagrange multipliers hit the upper bound)

Comment: I did what you say, and I got the same problem!